# copy from a list to another list with append() in python

Tags: python, list, copying

i need to copy a some member of my list to a new list without removing from original list.
i do this with append.
see my code :

```
    def add_citizens(self, value):
        for i in value:
            i.colony = self
            self.citizens.append(i)
```

actually after for loop , i removed from value list!
can any person say to me that copying with append is true? or there is a better way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can `self.citizens.extend(value)` after the loop, but that’s the same number of lines – just fewer calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add to the citizens list using this code:

```
class Citizens:

    def __init__(self):
        self.citizens = []

    def add_citizens(self, value):
        for i in value:
            self.citizens.append(i)

citizenClass = Citizens()
citizenClass.add_citizens(["Add", "Some", "Citizens"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but,i need to add to my list a dynamic list,your answer is solution for a static additional list.